# why interface and abstract methods can't be instantiated?

Tags: java

I am unable to figure out why instantiation of interface and abstract class is restricted in java. I know reference for implementation of interface and abstract class can be created. I am clear about that, but why it can't be instantiated? Anyone please help me

Comment: Do you mean "why" in the philosophical sense, or are you asking what mechanism in the compiler/runtime enforces that rule?

Comment: @LukeH I need the runtime mechanism

Answer (score 19):

The point of both an interface and an abstract class is to provide an API which has to be implemented in a concrete class.

For example, suppose I declare this interface:

```
public interface Foo
{
    int bar();
}
```

And imagine if this *were* valid code:

```
Foo foo = new Foo();
int x = foo.bar();
```

What could the value of `x` be? We haven't specified an implementation of `bar` anywhere. It's a meaningless call, without a *real* implementation to back it up.

Comment: I have made a minor edit to your example code. I hope this is what you originally intended.

Answer (score 4):

the If you think of a class as blueprints for creating (instantiating) an instance, much like the blueprints for a house tell you how to build a house.  Think of an interface as a floorplan for the house - its an incomplete view (specification) of the house.  There isn't enough detail to build the house from it - its only an outline of the rooms.  An abstract method is worse - its just the outline of one room.

Answer (score 2):

Interfaces and Abstract classes are not concrete classes.  They are deamed to be incomplete and not to be created.  You can use a subclass or implementing class.

Answer (score 1):

An Abstract class is a class that is not fully implemented. You want to force the developer to implement all the abstract parts of the class BEFORE he/she can instanciate it.

An Interface is a contract that a class must respect. As such, it cannot be instanciated. It can be important to define an Interface that a set of classes must respect in the case of a plugin system for example : All you plugins will share the same interface and thus will be inter-changeable.