# How to create an instance of an implementation in Google Guice

Tags: java, dependency-injection, guice, inject

I'm new to Google Guice and need a little help. I have created a module like this:

```
public interface Foo {
  Bar doSomething();
}

public class MyFoo implements Foo {
  Bar doSomething() {
    // create an instance of MyBar
  }
}

public interface Bar {
  void run();
}

public interface MyBar implements Bar {
  void run();
}

public class MyModule extends AbstractModule {

  @Override
  protected void configure() {
    bind(Foo.class).to(MyFoo.class);
  }      
}
```

My question is: What is the right way to create an instance of MyBar in class "MyFoo"? It feels wrong to just do this:

```
public class MyFoo implements Foo {
  Bar doSomething() {
    MyBar mybar = new MyBar();
    return mybar;
  }
}
```

Is there a way to inject a new instance of MyBar by MyModule when I need one, or do I have to inject a factory in the constructor of  MyBar for creating MyBar instances?
If I have to use a factory, can I control which implementation is generated via the module?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Maybe you are looking for providers? Providers are more or less factories which are part of the Guice API so you don't have to implement them.

```
public class MyFoo implements Foo {
  @Inject Provider<MyBar> myBarProvider;

  Bar doSomething() {
    return myBarProvider.get(); // returns a new instance of MyBar
  }
}
```

For details see https://github.com/google/guice/wiki/InjectingProviders

Comment: Exactly what i was looking for. Thanks

Comment: Worth mentioning, this is the first step toward complex-lifecycle handling in guice. You might find yourself in the future using more providers and running into difficulties (I did). The two key things that solved my problems were `@Assisted` inject (when you need to call a provider but you also need to give that provider some context (ie args) to help guice resolve a dependency), and en explicit provider method, (https://github.com/google/guice/wiki/ProvidesMethods), when you need to do more than simply have guice call a constructor (logging seems to be a common problem here)

Answer (score 0):

You can either go with Setter or Constructor [Injection](https://github.com/google/guice/wiki/Injections) like below:

```
public class MyFoo implements Foo {

    //constructor based injector
    @Inject
    public MyFoo(MyBar myBar){
        this.myBar=myBar;
    }

     //setter method injector
    @Inject
    public void setBar(MyBar myBar){
        this.myBar=myBar;
    }

    Bar doSomething() {
    // create an instance of MyBar
  }
}
```

`MyBar` is an `Interface` in your case [which can not be instantiated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5297896/why-interface-and-abstract-methods-cant-be-instantiated) ,you have to provide concrete implementation for the same, then bind in your `Module` and Inject it either through Setter or Constructor Injection as stated above.

**Setter Injection Example:**

**MyModule.java**

```
import com.google.inject.AbstractModule;

public class MyModule extends AbstractModule {

    @Override
    protected void configure() {
        bind(Foo.class).to(MyFoo.class);
        bind(Bar.class).to(MyBar.class);
    }
}
```

**MyBar.java**

```
public class MyBar implements Bar {

    public void run() {
        System.out.println("Hello Bar");
    }
}
```

**MyFoo.java**

```
import com.google.inject.Inject;

public class MyFoo implements Foo {
    private Bar bar;

    // setter method injector
    @Inject
    public void setBar(Bar myBar) {
        this.bar = myBar;
    }

    public Bar doSomething() {
        return bar;
    }
}
```

Comment: MyBar is nothing I want to inject. The method doSomething() must create an instance of MyBar and return it.